# How do I find the line on which a regex appears using Python

Tags: python, regex

How can I capture not only a match, but the line number on which it appears?

I have the following script:

`re.findall(pattern, a_file.read(), re.MULTILINE)`

Note: I have a lot of files to parse, and would prefer not to read (or reread) the file line by line.

Answer (score 3):

Try iterating through each line (with a count) to determine which line number a match can be found on. It could look something like this:

```
with open('somefile.txt', 'r') as a_file:
    linecount = 0
    for line in a_file:
        linecount += 1
        result = re.findall(pattern, line)
        ...
```

Comment: I think that will consume more memory and slow down the process considerably.

Comment: How large is your file? If you open a file at a time, this won't be an issue. Also, it's going to require iterating through the file one way or another. That can't be avoided.

Comment: It may also be worth mentioning that `re` can't track line numbers by itself, which is why it is going to require some sort of line iteration.

Comment: The files themselves are around 50 - 100 lines.  `f.read()` is supposed to be considerably more efficient than `f.readlines()`

Comment: Possibly. But in that case let me suggest `for i, line in enumerate(data)`.

Comment: Alright, you got me there; `readlines()` isn't necessary. Updated the code to reflect the change, and would also like to point out the `with` statement in case you weren't already doing that (they're a good idea).

Answer (score 0):

If you are parsing a lot of files, you should consider a shell-script based version of this code.  I absolutely love python, but knowing your way around UNIX tools is sometimes much easier.  Use the right tool for the right job.

If you have access to a Linux machine, or a command line emulator like [cmder](http://cmder.net/) you can do the following:

```
 find . -name "*.java" -exec grep -n -E "LOGGER.\w+\(" {} \;
```

The -n gets you the line number, and -E specifies that grep should look for a pattern, not a literal match.  This example looks for all *.java files in the current directory structure, (current folder and all subfolders) and searches each one it finds for strings like "LOGGER.info(", "LOGGER.debug(", "LOGGER.error(", which shows me all my logging statements in my java code, but not statements where the LOGGER is initialized.

You will generally find that this is also much faster than using a single python script over and over, or even looping through files with a python script.

Edit: One side note - if you are using a windows console emulator, the final `"\;"` is changed to a simple `";"`.